# LSTM prediction how to incorporate multiple autocorrelation

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, prediction, stat

I am working on a project which aims at prediction of highly autocorrelated time series. LSTM seems very ideal for my purpose. However, does anyone know how I can incorporate multiple large autocorrelation into my prediction networks? i.e., there is a very strong yearly correlation, and seasonal correlation; how am I able to include these information into the LSTM network?

Thank you sincerely

Comment: http://www.business-science.io/timeseries-analysis/2018/04/18/keras-lstm-sunspots-time-series-prediction.html
I got this implementation in R with stateful LSTMs in keras. See if this helps.

Comment: @UpasanaMittal. Thank you for your reply. I have seen that post as well, and it is a great work. However, i think the author inputs a past time series (the lagged time series) as an input for the training, which is not objective and automatic, right?

Answer (score 0):

if there is autocorrelation the correlation is *linear* ( not non-linear ) because common autocorrelation tests for linear correlation. Any LSTM is able to capture this linear correlations by default, it does not matter how many linear correlations are in the time series, the LSTM will capture it. A problem could be the length of memory , a LSTM has a memory between 200 and 500 timesteps ( https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-long-sequences-long-short-term-memory-recurrent-neural-networks/ ), so if the long-term linear correlations are in the time series at positions more extent than this the LSTM will not be able to capture because it lacks the memory ( not physical computer memory, the memory in the structure of LSTMs )

So simply build the LSTM model in keras and let it predict, 
as Upasana Mittal said in his comment, cf http://www.business-science.io/timeseries-analysis/2018/04/18/keras-lstm-sunspots-time-series-prediction.html

---

updated answer because there is not enough space in the comments. In http://www.business-science.io/timeseries-analysis/2018/04/18/keras-lstm-sunspots-time-series-prediction.html is used a *lagged time series* to determine ACF, this is objective else it would be impossible to determine ACF :

> First, we need to review the **Autocorrelation Function (ACF), which is
>   the correlation between the time series of interest in lagged versions
>   of itself**. The acf() function from the stats library returns the ACF
>   values for each lag as a plot. However, we’d like to get the ACF
>   values as data so we can investigate the underlying data. To do so,
>   we’ll create a custom function, tidy_acf(), to return the ACF values
>   in a tidy tibble.

There is no use of a specially lagged time series as input and using the history of the system or past system states to predict the future system states i also an objective ansatz and essential in any RNN.

So the way of proceeding in http://www.business-science.io/timeseries-analysis/2018/04/18/keras-lstm-sunspots-time-series-prediction.html is objective.

Another point you could mean is the *stateful* mode however it is vital that you use it because only in stateful mode the samples are not shuffled and accuracy is increased. *Stateless neural nets* work on probability distributions and shuffling a probability distribution does not change it ( *permutation invariance* ), *stateful neural nets* include the sequential ordering of the data so shuffling changes the result, search net for '*shuffling multifractal data*' :

> In normal (or “stateless”) mode, Keras shuffles the samples, and the
>   dependencies between the time series and the lagged version of itself
>   are lost. However, when run in “stateful” mode, we can often get high
>   accuracy results by leveraging the autocorrelations present in the
>   time series.

LSTMs by definition use a time series and a lagged version of the time series (`timesteps`,...), so this is also an objective ansatz.

If you want to dig deeper into the matter, and *go beyond linear correlations that are captured by ACF*, you should learn about *nonlinear dynamical systems* ( chaos theory, fractality, multifractality ) because it involves nonlinear systems and nonlinear correlations, i.e. the lag plot of a time series of a nonlinear dynamical systems in its chaotic state always exhibits the species of nonlinearity. The lag plot of the Logistic Map in its chaotic region shows a parabola, the lag plot  of a cubic nonlinear map shows a cubic curve,.... RNNs are only capable to model / approximate systems *perfectly accurate* whichs lag plot shows a sufficiently simple structure ( circles, spirals, lemniscates, cubic curves, quadratic curves , ... ), i.e. for a neural net it is impossible to approximate the sequence of the primegaps because the *lag plot of the sequence of primegaps*  is structured to complex ( however it shows a clear pattern for lag = 1, *when neglecting the sequential ordering* )

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the sunspots one, I think the author generates past sequence of the sunspot as an input in the training set using the large ACF, which is subjective, right?